# Python selenium won't switch frames

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I run

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.speedyshare.com/")

driver.switch_to.frame(0)

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("selectfilebox")
elem.click()
```

AND

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.speedyshare.com/")

frame_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/frameset/frame").get_attribute("name")

driver.switch_to.frame(frame_name)

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("selectfilebox")
elem.click()
```

They both keep running with no tracebacks but the mouse stays in the address bar.

When I change the fram index to 1 I get the following.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ro/selem.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver.switch_to.frame(1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/switch_to.py", line 67, in frame
    self._driver.execute(Command.SWITCH_TO_FRAME, {'id': frame_reference})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: Unable to locate frame: 1
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.switchToFrame (file:///tmp/tmpyickpa63/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10717)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpyickpa63/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12617)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpyickpa63/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12622)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpyickpa63/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12564)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you are switching to the appropriate `iframe` correctly.

Your actual problem is that you don't have to click the upload box - *it would trigger a File Upload popup which you simply cannot control*.

If you want to upload a file, you need to "send keys" the file input directly:

```
upload_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#selectfilebox input[type=file]")
upload_input.send_keys("/absolute/path/to/the/file/to/upload")
```

Complete working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.speedyshare.com/")

driver.switch_to.frame(0)

upload_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#selectfilebox input[type=file]")
upload_input.send_keys("/Users/user/Downloads/dr-evil-and-minion-laughing.png")

upload_button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Upload")
upload_button.click()
```